# Как в Aptana 3 развернуть окно на весь экран

Tags: aptana

**Как в Aptana 3 развернуть окно редактируемого кода/текста на весь экран с помощью горячих клавишь?**

Есть способ просто щёлкнуть 2 раза по окну как показано на картинке (1), но это не совсем удобно.

[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

Answer (score 1):

F11 попробуйте нажать. В большинстве программ тоже можно использовать F11.

Comment: Нет, не работает

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl + M - развернуть окно редактора на весь экран (и обратно) как в Eclipse